# Como liberar memória após o uso de um FileRerence?

Tags: actionscript-3, desempenho, memória

`FileReference.load` não possui uma função para descarregar, assim como existe `new Loader().unload`.

Deve ser um BUG do Flash ou FileReference precisa ser melhorado, tipo em uma nova versão adicionarem uma função assim: `FileReference.unload();`

Ou estou enganado e existe uma SOLUÇÃO?

Tentei setar `NULL` para uma variavel do tipo `:FileReference`, mas claramente isto não funciona por que o Flash trabalha com GC (garbage collector), mas este não é o foco da questão.

O problema é que ao carregar vários arquivos com `FileReferenceList` é necessário muita memoria, mas não consigo liberar memória após o processo.

Como liberar memória após o uso de um `FileRerence`?

Meu código:

### Main.as

```
package {
     import com.mainpackage.LoaderTestCase;

     import flash.net.FileReferenceList;
     import flash.net.FileReference;
     import flash.net.FileFilter;
     import flash.events.Event;
     import flash.display.MovieClip;

     public class Main extends MovieClip {
          private var listFiles:Array;
          private var allTypes:Array;
          private var fileRef:FileReferenceList;
          private var test:int;

          public function Main()
          {
               test = 0;
               listFiles     = [];
               allTypes     = [];
               fileRef          = new FileReferenceList();
               fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, select);

               fileRef.browse(allTypes);
          }

          private function select(e:Event):void
          {
               listFiles = fileRef.fileList;

               for(var i:uint=0, j:uint=listFiles.length; i<j; i++)
               {
                    insert(i);
               }
          }

          private function insert(c:int):void
          {
               var fire:LoaderTestCase = new LoaderTestCase(listFiles[c]);

               fire.destroy(function():void
               {
                    //Delete LoaderTestCase after timeout ???
                    fire = null;
                    test++;
                    if(test>=listFiles.length) {//Remove FileReference
                         fileRef.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, select);
                         fileRef = null;

                         for(var i:uint=0, j:uint=listFiles.length; i<j; i++) {
                              listFiles[i] = null;
                         }
                         listFiles = null;

                         trace("Clear memory");
                    }
               });
          }
     }
}
```

### LoaderTestCase.as

```
package com.mainpackage
{
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Loader;

    public class LoaderTestCase
    {
        private var file:FileReference;
        private var loader:Loader;
        private var callback:Function;

        public function LoaderTestCase(e:FileReference)
        {
            file = e;
            trace("OPEN: " + file.name);
            file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadFile);
            file.load();
            e = null;
        }

        public function loadFile(e:Event):void
        {
            file.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadFile);

            trace("LOAD: " + file.name);

            file    = null;
            e       = null;
            callback();
        }

        public function destroy(a:Function):void
        {
            callback = a;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu consegui chegar ao meu objetivo, descobri algo com `FileReferenceList.fileList`

Se eu fizer isto `FileReferenceList.fileList[5] = null;` (quando o "sexto arquivo" não está mais sendo usado) o Flash libera imediatamente a memoria deste `FileReference` especifico.

O que eu quero dizer com isto é que se você fizer isto o Flash não libera memória:

```
private var file:FileReference;
...
file = FileReferenceList.fileList[5];
...
file = null;
```

Porém isto libera a memória "imediatamente":

```
FileReferenceList.fileList[5] = null;
```

Funcionou em todos, no Adobe Flash Professional, Plugins instalado na máquina e PepperFlash (Plugin do Chrome).

Código em funcionamento:

```
package {
    import flash.net.FileReferenceList;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.net.FileFilter;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var listFiles:Array;
        private var allTypes:Array;
        private var fileRef:FileReferenceList;
        private var tmpFile:FileReference;
        private var i:uint=0;
        private var j:uint=0;
        private var timer:uint;
        private var imageTypes:FileFilter;
        private var enable:Boolean;

        public function Main()
        {
            imageTypes   = new FileFilter(
                "Images (*.JPG;*.JPEG;*.JPE;)", "*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe;"
            );
            listFiles   = [];
            allTypes    = [imageTypes];

            eventBrowse(true);
        }

        private function eventBrowse(a:Boolean):void
        {
            enable = a;
            if (a === true) {
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, browse);

                fileRef = new FileReferenceList();
                fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, select);
            } else {
                fileRef.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, select);
                fileRef = null;

                stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, browse);
            }
        }

        private function browse(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (enable === true) {
                fileRef.browse(allTypes);
            }
        }

        private function select(e:Event):void
        {
            listFiles = fileRef.fileList;

            eventBrowse(false);

            i = 0;
            j = listFiles.length;

            if (j > 0) {
                loadNextFile();
            }
        }

        private function loadNextFile():void
        {
            if (false === (i < j)) {
                listFiles = null;
                trace("Free memory???");
                trace("--------------");
                trace("listFiles:"+ listFiles);
                trace("allTypes:" + allTypes);
                trace("fileRef:" + fileRef);
                trace("tmpFile:" + tmpFile);
                trace("i:" + i);
                trace("j:" + j);
                trace("timer:" + timer);
                trace("--------------");
                eventBrowse(true);
                return;
            }

            tmpFile = listFiles[i];
            trace("Initiate load:" + tmpFile.name);
            tmpFile.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadedFile);
            tmpFile.load();
        }

        private function loadedFile(f:Event):void
        {
            trace(listFiles);
            trace("Finished load:" + tmpFile.name);
            tmpFile.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadedFile);

            tmpFile = null;
            listFiles[i] = null;

            ++i;
            loadNextFile();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito bom @GuilhermeNascimento!

Answer (score 2):

Isso não se trata de um *bug*. Na verdade o [Coletor de Lixo (Garbage Collector)](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c3-576ba64d124318d7189-7ffc.html) do Flash Player é executado de maneira imprevisível. Ele é o responsável por manter a memória ram da máquina livre e temos que levar isso em consideração sim.

Infelizmente não há como a liberar memória da máquina instantaneamente (com exceção da classe `BitmapData` que dispõe de um método chamado [.dispose()](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#dispose%28%29)), logo que o Coletor de Lixo só é executado quando realmente necessitar liberar a memória e também, não há controle deste objeto por parte do Programador e sim pela própria VM do Flash Player.

A própria referência da Adobe sugere/determina que para que o *GC* "destrua" os objetos não utilizados você defina as instâncias para os mesmos como `null`, que na maioria das vezes o ativa.

O que pode estar ocorrendo com seu código é que o *GC* ainda não está apto para captar os objetos que não estão instanciados, pois o objeto em si foi carregado em assíncrona através de um `Event`, o que impossibilita a definição `null`, já que a única maneira de acessá-lo é por um método "somente seitura" `e.currentTarget()`.

Não é uma particularidade somente do Flash, como dito, há outras linguagens que utilizam esse mesmo esquema. Entretanto o Flash ainda está muito atrás de obter essa perfeição.

Não sei qual o objetivo final da sua aplicação após carregar os arquivos, mas você poderia tentar carregá-los em um mesmo objeto `ByteArray`, dividindo cada arquivo por partes, gravando e depois gerar o arquivo final de cada um e após, definir este objeto como `null`.

Outra maneira é você construir uma "Gambiarra", mandando o seu frame atual para um totalmente vazio e sem funções (Como outra Cena, por exemplo), isso geralmente ativa o *GC*.

Comment: Recriei o código de maneira Async, só com um classe. Obitive os seguintes resultados: 1) "Firefox/Safari (Flash plugin 12.0.0.77): Inicia com 9Mb, atinge 135Mb e ao terminar está com 17Mb." 2) "Google Chrome (PepperFlash 12.0.0.70): Inicia com 12Mb, atinge 132Mb e ao terminar está com 17Mb."
3) "Flash CS5 (Flash Player 10/12 sem rodar CS5): Inicia com 6Mb, atinge 185Mb e ao terminar está com 185Mb."

Comment: Já foi uma bela de uma diferença! Realmente rodando o Flash Player direto no Desktop não irá haver mudança, acredito que na web o GC ainda rode com mais perfeição.

Comment: Estranhamente o Flash CS5 (IDE) usa o próprio aplicativo `./Adobe Flash CS5/Release/FlashPlayer.exe` para fazer o serviço e fiz um teste usando o [MonsterDebugger](http://www.demonsterdebugger.com) e ele mostra que libera quase toda memoria, o problema realmente só ocorre quando o FlashPlayer roda sem o IDE.