# Duvida com as Classes e Objetos do ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

### Descrição do Projeto

Estou desenvolvendo um catálogo em slide, em que existem fotos e textos, que são carregados dinamicamente a partir de urls fornecidas numa lista.

Carregar lista que apresenta este formato:

```
nome_do_item url_da_sua_imagem url_da_sua_descrição
```

Exemplo:

```
produtoA http://www.empresa.com.br/img/produtoA.png http://www.empresa.com.br/desc/produtoA.txt
```

A imagem em flash consiste no seguinte:

- 1° Camada (fundo): imagem de fundo;
- 2° Camada (botoes_items): retângulo lateral com um botão para cada item ;
- 3°Camada (mascara_botoes_items): máscara para que apenas os botoes no centro do retângulo lateral apareçam;
- 4° Camada (up_down): botões para descer e subir os botoes de items;
- 5° Camada (palco): apresenta a imagem do item grande e sua descrição logo abaixo;

### Dúvidas

- Para cada vez que puxar os arquivos das urls e necessário limpar a biblioteca?
- Como criar dinamicamente botões com a imagem dos Items, e inseri-los em um retângulo, que sirva como contêiner, para poder mover apenas o retângulo e não todos os botões?
- Ao clicar em um botão de item, para alterar a imagem e a descrição do palco, usando ActionScript, devo criar um frame para cada item?, ou apenas selecionar um retângulo e um TextField como palco e alterar seu valor?

Se possível, também ajudaria saber apenas as Classes que devo ter conhecimento para este trabalho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **VM** do ActionScript (Flash Player) possui um [Coletor de Lixo (Garbage Collector)](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c3-576ba64d124318d7189-7ffc.html), que é executado, de tempo indeterminado, para remover objetos que não estão sendo usados pelo seu projeto. [(Este link pode te ajudar)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11123/como-liberar-mem%C3%B3ria-ap%C3%B3s-o-uso-de-um-filererence).

Agora, para transformar uma imagem em um objeto "clicável" você pode carregá-la dentro de um objeto `MovieClip` e alterar a propriedade `buttonMode` para **true**. O ActionScript é [orientação a eventos](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e54.html), assim como o JavaScript, para você *ouvir* o click do mouse você utiliza o método `addEventListener`. Para aplicar máscara à eles, apenas altere o parâmetro `mask` para o MC máscara. Veja o exemplo:

```
var botaoMC:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
botaoMC.buttonMode = true;
botaoMC.mask = mascaraMC;
botaoMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicouMouse);

function clicouMouse(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("Clicou com mouse sobre o MovieClip");
}
```

Para exibir os itens no palco, você pode utilizar apenas um MovieClip e um TextField único, alterando as informações contidas dentro deles. É a melhor prática em relação a criar frames, tendo em vista que cada frame irá conter um objeto diferente e consequentemente o nível de processamento/memória do aplicativo. Inclusive você pode criar um método para isso, creio que algo parecido como abaixo:

```
function alterarSlide(img:Bitmap, str:String):void {
     for(var i:int = 0; i < imagemMC.numChildren; i++) {
         imagemMC.removeChildAt(i);
     }
     imagemMC.addChild(img);
     //img.width - Largura
     //img.height - Altura
     texto_txt.text = str;
}
```