# Adobe Air iOS - Unload Swf

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, adobe-air

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer `unload` de um `swf` no iOS. Actualmente estou a fazer um projecto em iOS usando Adobe Air e a minha classe é a seguinte:

```
function foo()
{

var m_lc:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain, null);

CustomUrl = new URLRequest(swfName.swf");

myLoader.load(CustomUrl,m_lc);

}

function unloadSWF(){
myLoader.unloadAndStop();
}
```

Na consola ele faz o `Load` do swf, mas não faz `unload` do respectivo `swf`, nem mesmo chamando o `garbage collector` ele limpa. Existe alguma maneira eficiente de limpar o `swf` em memória?

Answer (score 0):

Tenha certeza que todas as referências deste objeto carregado foram definidas como "null", ou seja, ao carregar você incorpora o objeto dentro de uma variável, por exemplo.

```
var swf:MovieClip = myLoader.content as Movieclip;
```

E assim que você executar o método `unload()` ou `unloadAndStop()`, você definir esta variável para null. Se você for utilizar o segundo método, defina o parâmetro `gc` como **true**.

```
swf = null;
myLoader.unloadAndStop(true);
```

É importante também você remover o objeto do `stage` caso o tenha adicionado e os ouvintes de eventos e afins.

Fazer o mesmo para qualquer outra variável que esteja referenciando o objeto carregado. Ao fazer isto, execute o código `System.gc();` para "forçar" a execução do coletor de lixo.

[Esta minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11123/como-liberar-mem%C3%B3ria-ap%C3%B3s-o-uso-de-um-filererence/11433#11433) pode te ajudar.